# Convert moment.js to date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, date-fns

I need to convert this from moment.js `moment(date, 'DD MM YYYY').isBefore(moment())` to date-fns.
I tried `isBefore(format(value, 'dd-MM-yyyy'), sub(new Date(), { days: 1 }))`. I mention that now I have to substract 1 day.
So the functionality will be to compare `value` which is the date given with currentDate - 1 day.
Essentially, check if future date is given, (future date includes current day).
Hope this is clear enough. My example doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: The date-fns [isBefore](https://bit.dev/date-fns/date-fns/is-before) documentation says that the first parameter is of type Date | Number.

Comment: @jarmod tried this also ```isBefore(format(new Date(value), 'dd-MM-yyyy'), sub(new Date(), { days: 1 }))```, but still it doesn't work

Comment: The format function yields a string. That's not a Date | Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using `format` instead of `parse`. `isBefore` accepts a `number` or `Date` not a string as its first argument.

See example:

```
function compareDate(value: string) {
  return isBefore(
    parse(value, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date()),
    sub(new Date(), { days: 1 })
  );
}

const test = compareDate('31-12-2020');
console.log(test);
```

### As requested in comments

We can run the value against a function that replaces all `/` and `\s` to `-`.

```
function unifyDateString(value: string) {
  try {
    return value.split("/").join("-").split(" ").join("-");
  } catch {
    return value;
  }
}

function compareDate(value: string) {
  return isBefore(
    parse(unifyDateString(value), "dd-MM-yyyy", new Date()),
    sub(new Date(), { days: 1 })
  );
}

const one = compareDate("31-12-2020");
const two = compareDate("31/12/2020");
const three = compareDate("31 12 2020");

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);
```

Comment: I'm having now another problem, if the value can be ```dd-MM-yyyy```, but also ```dd/MM/yyyy``` or ```dd MM yyyy``` , how can I parse all of these formats ?

Comment: I tried this solution, but it's not working.. somehow it doesn't parse any variant.

Comment: @Katerin1122 It's difficult to help you as the provided example works, please provide your code or else we can't help you properly

Comment: I've resolved this issue, in parse() ```date.replace(/[\/ ]/g, '-') ...```. Thank you for your time.